# web api equivalent to [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Result")]

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, web, .net-4.5

I'm trying to convert our WFC project to Web API. The requirement includes to not change the UI scripts/code and retain its current implementation. Now, I've encountered this [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Result")] attribute in WFC.
I'd like to know if it has an equivalent attribute in Web API that works.
If not then how do you guys do this in Web API?

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke....etc..]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "Result")] //this line of code
    public Person GetCurrentUser(string token)
    {
        ....
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see MessageParameter equivalent in WebApi as serialization would take care of this thing by just changing property name for that object. I've mostly used Json.NET as serializer where you can define custom property with `JsonProperty` attribute.

Comment: With web api you can return IHttpActionResult and within the method return an instance of `Result` which will be a class with same properties as `Person`.

Comment: Yes both of you are correct, I used JObject as parameter and I can also use IHttpActionResult or HttpResponseMessage as a return object.